# Path gets copied with the files in the folder to a new destination

Tags: linux, deployment, path, visual-studio-code

I'm using Deploy extension in VS-CODE to deploy a published ASP.NET Core Angular app straight to the production server via SFTP.

Everything runs smoothly except for one thing. In my settings.json in VS Code I make the appropriate arrangements as stated by Marcel Kloubert [here](https://github.com/mkloubert/vs-deploy).

```
{
"deploy": {
    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "JTrade Master Publish",
            "description": "Package version 1.0.0",
            "files": [
                "/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish/*"
            ],

            "deployOnSave": false
        }

    ],

    "targets": [
        {
            "type": "sftp",
            "name": "prod",
            "description": "JTrade Production version",
            "dir": "/var/testdeploy",
            "host": "139.162.216.36", "port": 22,
            "user": "root", "password": "*************"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

So this is the path to the folder where all the files I need are located on my hard drive localy: "/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish/* " and I set in the "files" setting above.

This is the directory on the server "dir": "/var/testdeploy" where I want everything to be at.

SO, the transfer goes fine, but I get this:

/var/testdeploy/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish/all my files here

and I want

/var/testdeploy/all my files here

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [mappings](https://github.com/mkloubert/vs-deploy/wiki/folder_mappings) section of the wiki to remap source directories to output directories. In your case, you need to add this to your targets:

```
"mappings": [{
    "source": "/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish",
    "target": "/"
}]
```